# HTTP authentication works correctly on local server but incorrectly on remote server

Tags: php, http, authentication, http-authentication

Can anyone please tell me why on a remote server when I type the correct username and password, it still tells me that the password is incorrect, while on a local server it all works fine? Thank You!

```
<?php
$username = sha1("random");
$password = sha1("random"); 
if((!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) || 
(sha1($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) != $username || sha1($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) != $password)){
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm='My realm'");
    exit("Please enter the correct password");
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the software setup the same on both servers?

Comment: Turn on error reporting, check error logs, maybe sha1() is throwing errors or notices? edit: Note there is nothing wrong with your code, tested here working fine

Comment: Is PHP_AUTH_PW/PHP_AUTH_USER defined on both servers?

Comment: Thanks to all. I just ended up using .htaccess authentication. But yes I do think that my PHP_AUTH_PW/PHP_AUTH_USER are just not set.